# Python: How to aggregate edge labels in Networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have an example of edges shown below and currently, my edge_labels is showing me the latest "price" of 200 for edge (a,b) instead.

I wonder how I can do an aggregate to the same edges when I draw the graph. Please see the illustration below.

Edit: The illustration should be a DiGraph instead. So the price of 700 should include a to b and b to a.

```
(a,b,price=500)
(a,b,price=100)
(b,c,price=100)
(b,a,price=100)
```

My codes:

```
df:
Date        debit credit price
2/4/2021      a      b     500
3/4/2021      a      b     100
3/4/2021      b      c     100
5/4/2021      b      a     100

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'debit','credit',edge_attr='price',create_using=nx.DiGraph())

#Plot
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'price')
nx.draw(G,pos,with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: networkx draw illustration]

Comment: Hi - can you share the code you use to make the graph?  Is it a MultiGraph?

Comment: Hi, I have added the codes. I'm using DiGraph

Comment: It might be easier to aggregate prices in pandas using `groupby` before passing to networkx.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Hi my bad, if in the event i wanted to filter by dates as well in the visualization, then will `groupby` still work?

Comment: @GabrielChoo I can't see why not. You can compute a dataframe containing only the latest prices and use it as input to networkx.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I realized `groupby` doesn't work for DiGraph in the event i have the edge of (b,a). Is there other ways to counter this?

Comment: Your data has two a->b edges.  Do you want them both to be stored, or do you want to store it as a single a->b edge with price 600?  If you want both to be stored, you'l need to use `MultiDiGraph`, not `DiGraph`.

Comment: I want them to be stored as a single price of 600. But when I changed it to `MultiDiGraph`, it raises an error "too many values to unpack" for `draw_networkx_edge_labels`